# Spotify Web API won't work for a specific user?

Tags: spotify, spotify-app

I'm trying to use the web api to query a user's playlists (using the spotipy Python library). I got the user to oAuth in, got an access token, made the request and got a 500 error:

```
SpotifyException: http status: 500, code:-1 - https://api.spotify.com/v1/users/125139403/playlists?limit=50&offset=0: Server error.
```

I then tried the same request in Web API test console and it worked fine.

But then things get kind of weird. I tried running the cURL command the console generated in a terminal and got the same 500 error.

Then I tried running the same request using cURL but just changing the username in the URL and it worked fine (at least for public playlists) for both my username and a random friend's user ID number.

I thought maybe I'm having a token issue but the token I'm using seems to work fine with other usernames. It's just the one specific user for whom I'm getting the error.

I'd rather not post the user's ID on this public forum but I can email it to someone if it's relevant.

My best guess for what's wrong at this point is a bug on Spotify's side but I certainly could be doing something wrong.

Comment: This is a known issue and we're working on a fix. Thanks for reporting!

Comment: Try that again and please let us know if you still have problems.

Answer (score 0):

Again, thanks for reporting this. This bug was fixed by Matt M. and was just deployed to production.

Please [try it out](https://developer.spotify.com/web-api/console/get-playlists/?user_id=125139403) in our API Console. (which Matt was also part of building!)